# JSP evaluation of Parameters

Tags: java, http, jsp

I was never really sure what the cleanest way would be to use JSP-Pages for receiving sent parameters. It's common knowledge to use as little JSP as possible - yet as some things have to be done there, for example the `request.getParameter`-Commands.

Right now most of my pages which are fetching parameters look like that, but I'm still not sure if this is clean enough:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%!
int id=0;
double price = 0;
%>
<%
    String article = request.getParameter("article");

    try {
        price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nufo) {
    } catch (NullPointerException nupo) {
    }

        try {
        id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nufo) {
    } catch (NullPointerException nupo) {
    }

    String user = session.getAttribute("user").toString();
%>
<jsp:useBean class="mybean.UsedBean" id="beanie" scope="page">
    <jsp:setProperty name="beanie" property="article" value="<%=article%>"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="beanie" property="id" value="<%=id%>"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="beanie" property="price" value="<%=price%>"/>
    <jsp:getProperty name="beanie" property="update"/>
</jsp:useBean>
```

`setArticle`, `setId`, `setPrice` are just regular setters while `getUpdate` is the method which actually "does" something and returns either true/false, the number of affected lines in the database or some sort of string.

Yet I doubt if this could be done better.

Skipping the receiving-part and directly forwarding the parameters to the fields via:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="para" value="<%=request.getParameter("para")%>"/>
```

Attribute value `request.getParameter("para")` is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value is causing an exception:

```
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Project] threw exception [/project/GetForm.jsp (line: 70, column: 77) Attribute value request.getParameter("para") is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value] with root cause  
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /project/GetForm.jsp (line: 70, column: 77) Attribute value request.getParameter("para") is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value
```

[This question has been asked already several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501265/simple-error-due-to-use-of-double-quotes-in-a-jsp-file) but I'm not sure if I want to "have it solved".

I don't want to have `int` or `double` fields in my bean which have String-setters.

Also having a `setRequest` method in every bean does not really seem to be the best possible way either.

So for my purposes - is the way I'm using the JSPs correct? Or what would be better?

Comment: Is your code broken or working?

Comment: Just to make sure: Is it or is it not working to the best of your knowledge? Is it doing what you want it to do?

Comment: Code is working and it's doing what I want it to do, but I'm not sure if there are cleaner or better ways to get the job done.

Comment: I suggest you should take a look at EL for reading values from Java beans in JSP. Because either a JSP tag or a scriptlet is too verbose, it leads less readable code. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Btw, why didn't you create the bean **beanie** in a servlet and pass it to JSP? So we can get rid of the significant amount of redundant code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @HungTran. I'm not in the impression EL would be a better solution since it's just the evaluation and conversion of parameters. In contrast using a servlet instead of a "jsp-receiver" sounds pretty reasonable. Especially for beans with just a smaller functionality. I'd love to vote you up for that.